# Solving exponential equations like $6^{3x}=4^{2x-3}$ using logarithms

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve these using logarithms:

$a$) $9^{x+1} = 27^{2x-3}$

$b$) $6^{3x} =4^{2x-3}$

$c$) $210=40(1.5)^x.$

---

I'm trying to practice logarithms by doing various questions. It's been a while since I've done them, so I was hoping to refresh on them a bit. Hoping someone can walk me through the steps.

I'm not sure how to go about a, so since a and b are so similar I will probably have difficulty with both. C I Wasn't sure if I should start with finding a common base (since I could get a common base of 2 with them without too much difficulty) first or if I should go ahead and take the log of both sides. I'm trying to think reverse logarithm laws as well, but for these questions I'm just not sure of what I should do first. If I see how to do a or b I should be able to figure out the other. But C I may need some guidance

Comment: Have you tried? Can we see what you have done?

Comment: I'm trying to practice logarithms by doing various questions.  It's been a while since I've done them, so I was hoping to refresh on them a bit.  Hoping someone can walk me through the steps.

Comment: I can do c) for an example if you would like?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about a, so since a and c are so similar I will probably have difficulty with both.  C I Wasn't sure if I should start with finding a common base (since I could get a common base of 2 with them without too much difficulty) first or if I should go ahead and take the log of both sides.  I'm trying to think reverse logarithm laws as well, but for these questions I'm just not sure of what I should do first.  If I see how to do a or b I should be able to figure out the other.  But C I may need some guidance

Comment: @user209097 Consider taking the logarithm of both sides of the equation, for all three parts.

Comment: would be useful to see where you are struggling at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** 
$$\log(a^b) = b \log(a) \\
\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)
$$

Example for part $c)$:

$$
210 = 40(1.5)^x \\
\log(210) = \log(40 (1.5)^x) \\
\log(210) = x\log(1.5) + \log(40) \\
\frac{\log(210) - \log(40)}{\log(1.5)} = x \\
x \approx 4.0897
$$

Answer (score 0):

In reference to Axoren, the following is true for (1):
\begin{align}
9^{x+1}=27^{2x-3} & \implies\left(3^2\right)^{x+1}=\left(3^3\right)^{2x-3}\tag{1}\\[1em]
 & \implies \left(3\right)^{2x+2}=\left(3\right)^{6x-9}\tag{2} \\[1em]
& \implies \left(2x+2\right)\log_3\left|3\right|=\left(6x-9\right)\log_3\left|3\right|\tag{3}\\[1em]
& \implies 2x+2=6x-9\tag{4} \\[1em]
& \implies \boxed{x=\frac{11}{4}.}\tag{5}
\end{align}
I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: The answer I got for b) was 3.44.  Let me know if there must be an error

Comment: Also for c), do I have to divide both sides by 40 first before I can do anything else?

Comment: @user209097 You can divide first, there's nothing saying you cannot, that's part of the rules. Notice after you divide that you must then take the logarithm with base 1.5, so you have $$\log_{1.5}\left|\frac{21}{4}\right|=\log_{1.5}\left|1.5^x\right|$$, but based on the laws of exponents and logs, you thus arrive at $$x=\log_{1.5}\left|\frac{21}{4}\right|.$$

Comment: @user209097 Notice for (b) that it is a bit trickier to get the bases of the exponents to line up with one another. The whole goal is to make them go away so you're left with the exponents and the variables in the exponents. So do anything you can that will allow the bases to become exponential multiples of the other base.